# How do i extract data from response and use it in url for next request in Burp Intruder?

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, attacks, burp-suite

The URL is `https://www.example.com/send?session=abcabcabc`.

When the above URL is requested, a response comes with `<a>` tag which contains a new URL with a different session value like `https://www.example.com/send?session=xyzxyzxyz`.

As you can notice, the session value has changed and it changed on each request.

So my question is how can I use Burp intruder to do a repeated request?

The workflow should be:

**Burp > request sent > gets response > take URL or session value from response > send request with updated session value in URL > loop continues.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [Recursive grep](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/tools/intruder/payloads/types#recursive-grep). The following would solve your problem;
- Set payload type as `Recursive grep`
- Then, from "Options" tab under `Grep - Extract`, add a match as required
- Set 'Number of threads' to 1 (because you need response from immediate next response)

There are several blog posts on this very topic, here's one from PortSwigger -https://portswigger.net/blog/using-recursive-grep-for-harvesting-data

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Burp Macro followed by a Session Handling Rule within Project Options tab.

> The following URL provides the detailed description of how to achieve this:
>
> https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/2906338-using-burp-s-session-handling-rules-with-anti-csrf-tokens

The Title of the topic on the website says "Using Burp's Session Handling Rules with anti-CSRF Tokens", however it does exactly what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: As I understand the original question, they need to repeatedly issue a request with a value updated from a response. A macro would be good for doing it a fixed number of times, but to do it repeatedly, recursive grep is required.

Comment: @PortSwigger, thanks for your feedback. I agree, in this particular instance, a recursive grep may be a better option.